# pyqt5: qMainWindow does not expand to centralWidget Size

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, pyqt5

I'm integrating openCV 3.0 with Qt5 in Python 3.4.3 using pyqt5. I've been trying to build an app to process videos from files, but ran into some trouble with pyqt. Specifically, I will be loading videos through a file dialog multiple times and these videos will not be the same size. Therefore, I want the main window in my app to wrap/expand to the size of the video being played.

Below is a simplified version of my code with the 3 core classes for showing the video. One for the Main Window, one for a frame viewer widget to show each video frame in the GUI, and one for a video processor to read and process the video through opencv, transform it to a QImage then send it to the viewer.

```
class videoProcessor(QtCore.QObject):
    filename = None
    cap = None    

    videoSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QImage)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.filename = "test.mp4"

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def runVideoProcessor(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.filename)

        while self.cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if ret:
                outimg = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                imgh, imgw, bytesPerComponent = outimg.shape
                bytesPerLine = bytesPerComponent * imgw;
                qtimg = QtGui.QImage(outimg.data,imgw,imgh,bytesPerLine,QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.videoSignal.emit(qtimg)
            else:
                break    
        self.cap.release()

class frameViewer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = QtGui.QImage()
        self.imageAvailable = False

    def paintEvent(self,event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(0,0,self.image)
        self.image = QtGui.QImage()
        painter.end()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QImage)
    def setFrame(self,image):
        self.image = image
        self.setFixedSize(self.image.size())
        self.repaint()

class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.fview = frameViewer()
        self.vproc = videoProcessor()
        self.vproc.videoSignal.connect(self.fview.setFrame)

        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.vproc.runVideoProcessor)

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.fview)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.startButton)

        self.mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.mainWidget.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('OpenCV PyQt Test')    
        self.show()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = mainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So far, the program can run videos but there are two main problems:

1. The window **does not adjust** to the size of the video frame until the end of the video. However, any repetition of the same video play will be in the correct size.
2. If I don't set `self.image=QtGui.QImage()` in `paintEvent` after drawing the image, **the program crashes**. However, if I put that line in, at the end of the video, the window will go blank because an empty `QImage` will be drawn in the last frame's place whenever the window is updated.

Any ideas on how to solve these issues? Thank you.